# Improving classification accuracy with TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

My goal is to predict whether a person is a Android, iOS, or a full stack developer.

I have 9 features I use to train my data, each feature is a trait such as `know_javascript` or `know_swift`. An Android developer has its corresponding probability for each of the 9 features, the same goes for the iOS and full stack dev.

For example, for an Android dev
`[100,80,60,80,20,10,50,60,10]` corresponds to an Android dev having a probability of `100% that this person knows java, 80% knows XML, 60% knows...etc`

A training data will be in the form of `[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]`. 1 means it has that trait, 0 means it doesn't.

I have trained my model according to the rules above, using TensorFlow's guide on classifying Iris sets:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/tflearn/

My code is almost exactly the same as this guide.

I'm able to achieve 75% accuracy with 3 layers, 10000 training and 4400 testing set.

I want to plot the bias and variance using TensorBoard, but I don't have biases or variances in my program.

2 Questions:

1. Advices on improving my accuracy?
2. How can I go about plotting a `learning_curve` or seeing the biases and variance?

Comment: With this size of samples and problem-structure, i suspect even a linear-classifier will do better out of the box and a tuned kernel-svm will approach something really good. NNs surely would not be my first attempt here. (And i don't understand how you start with integers in [0,100] and then only have binary values. I hope you don't throw away information here).

Comment: Try a simple decision tree algorithm or any other linear algorithm from scikit learn instead of using tensorflow. Why exactly did you minimize your vector values to binary